# How do I filter rows based on whether a column value is in a Set of Strings in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a more elegant way of filtering based on values in a Set of String?

```
def myFilter(actions: Set[String], myDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val containsAction = udf((action: String) => {
    actions.contains(action)
  })

  myDF.filter(containsAction('action))
}
```

In SQL you can do

```
select * from myTable where action in ('action1', 'action2', 'action3')
```

Comment: Have you looked at `myDF.action.inSet()` ?

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense to me. Have you worked with Spark DataFrames before?

Comment: Yes I have, using python. By the way, why don't you use the SQL version, since it works for you?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about this:

```
myDF.filter("action in (1,2)")
```

OR

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit       
myDF.where($"action".in(Seq(1,2).map(lit(_)):_*))
```

OR

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit       
myDF.where($"action".in(Seq(lit(1),lit(2)):_*))
```

[Additional support will be added to make this cleaner in 1.5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8348)

Comment: Thank you! Your examples enlightened me greatly.

Comment: Is this solution more efficient?

Comment: @VijayKrishna Versus a udf? Then of course it is more efficient. udf's are not optimizable.