# Read Array in sub queries spark sql using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to achieve this query using scala in spark sql

```
SELECT * FROM  employees
 WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT emp_id 
              FROM employees
              WHERE SALARY > 200) ;
```

I have mapped oracle table to spark data frame

```
val employees = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:client/password@localhost:1521:orcldb1", "dbtable" -> "client.EMPLOYEE"));
```

Output of subquery is following

```
scala> employees.where($"salary" > 100).select($"emp_id").collect().map{ row=>row.get(0)}

res3: Array[Any] = Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 2, 3, 5)
```

I'm getting following error while performing whole query

```
 employees.where($"emp_id" in (employees.where($"salary" > 100).select($"emp_id").collect())).show
```

`warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class [Ljava.lang.Object; [Ljava.lang.Object;@129df247
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:642)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)`

Comment: No that wasn't my expected answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551919/spark-filter-isin-doesnt-work-as-expected) is the one.

Comment: Some other options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33825337/1560062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer

```
val items = employees.where($"salary" > 100).select($"emp_id").collect().map{ row=>row.get(0)}
```

the only thing i changed is, i have used isin instead of in

```
employees.filter($"emp_id".isin(items:_*)).show
```